# get all the subviews of a cell onClick in UICollectionView swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to access all the subviews attached to the cell in `UICollectionView` when the cell is clicked.

I am able to add the image and label to it, but it shows nil when I tap on any cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)

  // Image      
  let imageview:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: myCell.frame.width - 10, height: myCell.frame.height - 20))
  imageview.image = UIImage(named: String(format: "%@.png", arr[indexPath.row]))
  imageview.tag = 20

  // Label
  let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 50, width: myCell.frame.width - 10, height: myCell.frame.height - 40))
  label.textAlignment = .center
  label.text = arr[indexPath.row]
  label.textColor = .black
  label.tag = 21
  label.font = label.font.withSize(8)

  myCell.contentView.addSubview(imageview) 
  myCell.contentView.addSubview(label)

  myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

  return myCell
}
```

and I am trying to access the subviews as below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
  print(myCell.contentView.subViews) // Returns null
}
```

I am aware that we can get the item index using `indexPath.row`. But I want read the subview. How to get it ? Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to use `cellForItem(at:)` to get cell, So it should be `let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)`

Comment: @NiravD, Yes, it worked now.  Thank you :)

Comment: Are you getting `subViews` nil if you cell with `cellForItem(at:)` like `let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath); print(cell.contentView.subviews)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
    print(myCell.contentView.subViews) // Returns always null 
}
```

The method of UICollectionView `dequeueReusableCell` returns a new reusable cell and now `myCell` have the new reference and always be new reference if you want to get your old cell you need to getting the cell from

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCell
```

if you have the class use `MyCell` else you can get cell directly without type casting.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    print(cell.contentView.subviews)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code is `didSelectMethod`

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
print(cell)
```